# How to display Error message on content part of Headered Content Control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am working on wpf application. I am very new to wpf. I am using "Headered Content Control" , Label as Header and Text Box as Content part. No problem with that. For Validation, I am using "IDataErrorInfo". I am able to display error but my problem is

i) Error Border displaying on complete Headered Contentcontrol (on both Label & On Tet Box), how can I display Red border only on TextBox...

ii) I am able to display error message when I placed cursor on border (as shown in the Image), but could not able to display error message when I placed cursor on text box..... 
Can any one help me how can I change the styles so that I can display error message on Text box tool tip...

here is style where I am displaying my error message...

```
<Style TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
        <Style.Setters>
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <!--<Border BorderBrush="Red" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" />
                        </Border>-->
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="red" 
                                    BorderThickness="1">                                
                            </Border> 
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
 </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance

My Headered Content Control code is :

```
 <HeaderedContentControl Header="Name" 
   Content="{Binding Path=ValidationClassProp.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Where Validation Class Inherits IDataErrorInfo...

Comment: Please provide xaml there you use your HeaderedContentControl, especially part with binding to your IDataErrorInfo data

Comment: Apply the template on `textbox` only instead of entire `HeaderContentControl`.

Comment: @RV1987 : Thanks for the Response... I tried that but even I am not able to achieve that.. when I tried using it for my textbox, I am not getting error message which I am returning...

Comment: WoodMan : Thanks for the response... Just now I Updated my question and added my Headered Content Control design code in the end of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Since the validation error template is set to display over an entire control, you just need to adjust the bindings on your data template so that the validation error template displays over the TextBlock inside the template, rather than the entire HeaderedContentControl.

I built a tiny app to demonstrate this. Here's the code:

**The Window's XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="_15001777.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_15001777"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HeaderedItem}">
                    <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Path=Header}">
                        <HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                           Content="Name" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=HeaderedContentControl}, Path=DataContext.Header, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
                    </HeaderedContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**The Window's Code-Behind**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace _15001777
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            Items.Add(new HeaderedItem { Header = "One" });
        }

        public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; private set; } 
    }

    public class HeaderedItem : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public object Header { get; set; }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get { return columnName == "Header" ? "There was an error!" : null; }
        }

        public string Error { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brandon : Thanks for the response & Example.. Will use this and try to check for the possibilities of separating my header part and Content part.. By the way Is there any possibility of achieving it with out changing my Xaml code and by only changing my styles (Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate") to apply styles only to content part of header control....

Comment: I believe there is a way to do this using only styles, but it would be a lot more complicated. Data templates were created for scenarios just like the one you described, so I'd highly recommend going that route as it will be easier for people following your work to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you facing is caused by the fact that you bind content property of `HeaderedContentControl` to property in your model. In this case whole `HeaderedContentControl`  is considered as *errored*

So the possible solution is to explicitly specify content of `HeaderedContentControl` and Bind to `Text` property of `TextBox` control

```xaml
<HeaderedContentControl Header="Name">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValidationClassProp.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

And apply your error template in style for `TextBox`

**EDIT**

Had a rough idea for to try and keep your current xaml.
You can try create `IValueConveter` which would take `AdornedElementPlaceholder` as value, cast it to `HeaderedContentControl` and try and get actual size and position of Content part of this control, after this prepare a `Thinkness` structure and return it as result. That `Thinkness` would be a `Margin` for your red border
So it whould be something like this:

```xaml
<AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="red"
                                Margin={Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Converter={StaticResource SomeCustomConverter}"
                                BorderThickness="1">                             
                        </Border> 
                    </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
```

Again this is not complete solution rather a possible direction, as it would be still no so easy to get the position of Content part...